# Disabling default XML Schemas in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, xsd, caml

I have recently started using [CAML.NET IntelliSense for SharePoint](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/camlintellisense/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2212) with Visual Studio 2008; which works great; however whenever I create a new project using STSDev 2008 (and thus generate feature.xml and WebParts.xml) the default schemas include the CAML.NET IntelliSense and the built-in (relatively incomplete) schemas:

- caml.xsd
- wss.xsd
- coredefinitions.xsd
- camlview.xsd

All found in web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\XML. The existence of both of these schemas for the file causes a large number of warnings, notifying me that a specific schema entry is already declared in one of the above files. Disabling them for each file individually works great, however in a SharePoint solution whit 40 or 50 XML files this quickly becomes laborious.

Is it possible to disable these built-in Schemas, selecting "Do not use selected schemas" does not work for future XML files only the current one?

Comment: Curiosity: why do you want them disabled? Also, if this is a problem, please suggest it on Connect (http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment John, I wan't to disable them because CAML.NET InteliSense for Sharepoint (as linked above) replaces the CAML functionality contained within the built in Schemas, this causes hundreds of xyz is already declared within caml.xsd/wss.xsd etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you really don't want them - you could remove the schemas from the xsd path (`%VsInstallDir%\xml\Schemas`) - and perhaps disable download (Options->TextEditor->Xml->Miscellaneous). My machine isn't in a suitable state to try it, but it should work in theory...

Comment: The CAML.net XML seems to cover at least everything that the built in XSDs do. That seems like a good solution to me - do you mind if I leave this to run for a few more days in case someone else spots it.